# Why the if statement is executed in ` if [ ''=1 ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`?

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
if test-commands; then
  consequent-commands;
[elif more-test-commands; then
  more-consequents;]
[else alternate-consequents;]
fi
```

> The test-commands list is executed, and if its return status is zero, the consequent-commands list is executed.

Show  status of `''=1` in bash.

```
''=1
bash: =1: command not found
echo $?
127
```

The value of status is 127, not zero. A strange statement:

```
if [ ''=1 ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
true
```

Why value of status `127`, not zero invoke then statement? Why can't get `false` in bash?

@Дмитрий Шатов

```
=1
bash: =1: command not found
echo $?
127
```

Comment: becouse bash interpritate this as string `'[' =1 ']'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You need spaces

`''=1` gets interpreted as a string `=1` and *test* finds a non-empty string. If you want to compare `''` to `1`, write

```
[ '' = 1 ]
```

## Why status 127?

`man bash`

> ... If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error message and returns an exit status of 127.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is a string comparison operation.

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
then
    echo 'true'
else
    echo 'false'
fi
```

You need to use `!=` rather than `=` when comparing the two strings. This will act as the opposite of the comparison `[ "$a" = "$b" ]`

```
if [ "$a" != "$b" ] 
then
    echo 'false'
else
    echo 'true'
fi
```